# passport-google-oauth20 not working in production?

Tags: node.js, express, google-oauth

It works fine in dev, but when I try to use it in production, once I select my google account it just keeps loading without redirecting until the connection times out. this is my googleStrategy code:

```
    passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
      proxy: true
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id }).then(existingUser => {
        if (existingUser) {
          done(null, existingUser);
        } else {
          new User({ googleId: profile.id })
            .save()
            .then(user => done(null, user));
        }
      });
    }
  )
);
```

I also tried using an absolute path in the callback URL, but it's not working.

Comment: are you using a `.env` file to determine the environment? what does your passport config look like? it might be that the `keys` may be reading only the dev correctly

Comment: @TimChosen I have the prod keys defined in the Heroku config, since that's where I'm trying to deploy. I recently erased them all and added every single one again to see if I had a typo somewhere but I don't think I do. 

I'm not exactly sure of what do you mean by passport config, I didn't mess a lot with it so it should be pretty much default.

Comment: I fixed it. I added 0.0.0.0/0 to the IP addresses that can write in the DB and it's working now.